# Vectorize associated Legendre polynoms with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to input a vector to my associated legendre polynoms.

```
import scipy.special as sp
def f(m,n,x):
    return sp.lpmn(m,n,x)[0][-1,-1]
x=[1,2,3]
print f(1,1,x)
```

The output is

```
ValueError: z must be scalar.
```

What can I do to input a vector to the associated legendre polynoms, eg for fitting and plotting? Vectorizing the function with numpy doesn't work:

```
np.vectorize(f(1,1,x))

>>>> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\basic.py", line 681, in lpmn
raise ValueError("z must be scalar.")

>>>> ValueError: z must be scalar.
```

Comment: How exactly does not vectorizing with numpy work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) takes a function as the first argument and returns a new function wrapping the original. When called like this:

```
np.vectorize(f(1,1,x))
```

it actually means "Call function f with arguments 1, 1 and x, pass result as first argument to np.vectorize". What you should do is decorate your function:

```
@np.vectorize
def f(m, n, x):
    return sp.lpmn(m, n, x)[0][-1, -1]
```

Testing:

```
In [4]: f(1, 1, [1, 2, 3])
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:1639: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ? (vectorized)
  outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
Out[4]: array([ 0.        ,  1.73205081,  2.82842712])
```

When used like this you have to be careful not to pass array values as order and degree to `f` (*m* and *n*), as they will also be vectorized, which will probably fail, or do unexpected things:

```
In [6]: f([1, 2], 1, [1, 2, 3])
 ...
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) () (3,)
```

`numpy.vectorize` can be told not to consider those arguments by passing a set of indexes of positional arguments and names of keyword arguments:

```
def f(m, n, x):
    return sp.lpmn(m, n, x)[0][-1, -1]
f = np.vectorize(f, excluded={0, 1}, otypes=[np.float64])
```